Re-decorate a python (class) decorator
I'd like to create a decorator that basically wraps an already existing decorator that has parameters, such that the new decorator acts like the old one with some of the arguments supplied.
Specifically, this is about the builtin @dataclass decorator. I have a number of classes to decorate with it, while always using kw_only=True and eq=False, and I'd like to have a new decorator that does just that, saving me to spell out the parameters every time. So, e.g. ...
@mydataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = 5

...should be equivalent to...
@dataclass(kw_only=True, eq=False)
class Foo:
    a: int = 5

I know this doesn't seem like saving a lot of typing, but well this is more about providing a convenience decorator for the rest of our team, so that no one forgets to correctly add these two parameters.

Do you just want the runtime functionality, or do you want to preserve the static type hinting that type checkers are hard-coded to do when they see dataclass?

I want to preserve the static type checking. Indeed I just tried the solutions below, and in both cases, mypy complains about "Unexpected keyword argument", which is bad.

@dataclass is handled specially by type checkers. The main reason is to infer the __init__ signature, but also other behavior. This is not inferred by normal decorators that wrap dataclass.
For correct handling by type checkers you need to decorate your decorator with typing.dataclass_transform which tells type checkers that your decorator is like @dataclass
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@typing.dataclass_transform(
    field_specifiers=(field,)
    kw_only_default=True,
    eq_default=False,
)
def mydataclass(cls):
    return dataclass(kw_only=True, eq=False)(cls)

@mydataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = 5

Foo(a=1)  # ok


Decorators are basically functions that take a function or a class as argument, so, you just have to create a new function taking a class as argument and returning the value of dataclass :
from dataclasses import dataclass

def mydataclass(cls):
    return dataclass(kw_only=True, eq=False)(cls)

@mydataclass
class Foo:
    a: int = 5


Since decorators are just functions, you just want to create a curried function which has some arguments already bound to it. Which is what partial does:
from functools import partial
from dataclasses import dataclass

mydataclass = partial(dataclass, kw_only=True, eq=False)

